# JNI stack sequence misunderstanding

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have the following code in a very simple JNI example (Java + C)

**Java**

```
    package jnitest;


public class JNITest {

  static {
    System.load("C:/.../JNItestNative.dll");
  }

  public native void hello();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JNITest jniTest = new JNITest();

    System.out.println("Hello in java");
    jniTest.hello();
    System.out.println("Bye in java");
  }
}
```

**C**

```
    /* 
 * File:   jnitestnative.c
 * Author: DEFAULT
 *
 * Created on February 17, 2012, 12:24 PM
 */

#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_jnitest_JNITest_hello
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {

  printf("Hello in C\n");
  printf("Bye in C\n");

  return;
}
```

I expect the result to be like this:

```
Hello in Java
Hello in C
Bye in C
Bye in Java
```

**But it is really like this:**

```
Hello in java
Bye in java
Hello in C
Bye in C
```

Comment: Could be that `System.out.println` buffers somewhere different than `printf`? Try writing to something else (like a file)?

Comment: Originally I faced this problem when I was changing the size of a passed char[] not only echoing to the console!

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin You are right, the result in a text file is as expected, but can we have such a problem when we are manipulating the Java Objects in C???

Comment: Not _that_ kind of problem, no. Maybe you should post the real code?

Answer (score 1):

When I run the code you posted I get the expected output. There may be some strange buffering going on due to the fact that `stdout` is buffered by the standard C library, while the JVM tends to bypass the C library and use OS calls directly.

If this is the case you can always flush `stdout` before returning from C:

```
printf("Hello in C\n");
printf("Bye in C\n");
fflush(stdout);
return;
```

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of too, but doesn't newline make `printf` flush the contents to `stdout`?

Comment: In theory, yes. But it won't hurt to check if an explicit fflush really doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Only when stdout is line buffered. It usually is but apparently there are cases when it isn't.